# Illustrator Javascript set font attributes

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I am relatively new to scripting for illustrator and I am having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

I would like to select some text (the whole range) and set some attributes to it.

I have named the text object in the layers panel and if possible, I would like to select it by name. (or any other easy/direct way you may suggest)

This is how I reference my objects by name.

```
 doc = app.activeDocument;
 doc.pageItems.getByName('myname');
```

I was hoping I could do keep it simple like so....

```
 doc.pageItems.getByName('myname').characterAttributes.size = 30;
```

Needless to say, this doesn't seem to work. I was looking into making `characterStyles` as well but that is much more complex so setting individual attributes would be my first step.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out.... I was missing the `.textRange` selector.

```
 doc.pageItems.getByName('myname').textRange.characterAttributes.size = 500;
```

This works great for most all of the attributes, I still can't seem to set the `.textFont` attribute by the font name. I can set it using the index, but that's no good as I update my fonts quite often.

```
 doc.pageItems.getByName('myname').textRange.characterAttributes.textFont = app.textFonts[7];
```

Even after retrieving the name of the font, I can't set it... I assumed the way would be something like...

```
 doc.pageItems.getByName('myname').textRange.characterAttributes.textFont = "Arial";
```

No Luck Though...

Comment: Try `..textFont.name = 'Arial';` (see `textFont` property in the [Reference](http://jongware.mit.edu/iljscs6html/iljscs6/pc_CharacterAttributes.html)).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getByName(name)` where `name` is the font's **full name** (i.e. including font style) as opposed to **family name**:

```
textRef.textRange.characterAttributes.textFont = app.textFonts.getByName("FiraSans-Book");
```

Answer (score -2):

You can set attributes with:

```
doc.pageItems.getByName('myname').setAttribute("id","foo");
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

You can set the style with:

```
doc.pageItems.getByName('myname').style.fontSize = "medium";
```

The whole list of things you can put behind '.style' is here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp

Comment: Thanks for the reply man, the problem is your answer is regarding standard JavaScript. My question was directed towards JavaScript for Adobe Illustrator. I appreciate your time though :)